# VS Code Install Chromebook - 'Failed to retrive app info'

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

trying to install vs code on my chromebook and getting that error message on the install. I am running on the beta version atm. This issue was also happening on my dads cb which is on the stable version of Chrome OS. Any help would be much appreciated :).

I followed the vs cide on site tutorial and installed the dependency but to no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a dumb answer, but since there are none, re-intalling the Linux environment on my Chromebook worked for me.